# Shortcode not working - quotes seems strange

Tags: plugins, php, shortcode

I have been through other posts and tried a lot.
I have two wordpress sites on the same server and A runs fine with the plugin "PHP code snippets" but B just shows the shortcode [wbcr_php_snippet id=”1656″]. On B i can use other shortcodes but have tried other plugins for php insertion and get to the same issue.

When looking at the shortcode at this page: https://mesthverdag.dk/boeger/ it looks like the quotes are different and the same in the html source. They are only edited in text and i have tried many things to ensure it is not just a typo.

I have tried to change the theme from Anissa to Amadeus and standard WP as site A uses and compared function.php but site B still comes up with same issue, that i do not have on site A.

Can something change the quotes? and can it be the issue?
This is what the source looks like: [wbcr_php_snippet id=”1656″] (the quotes seems different)

No errors are seen and i have reinstalled plugin.

UPDATE: i have tried to remove the fancy quotes in the themes functions.php bit it makes no difference, som seems not to be the quotes.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `"`, and not `”`. They're different characters. You can end up with the latter if you've copied them from a forum or blog post where the writer's CMS converts `"` to 'fancy quotes'. Just delete the quote marks and type them again yourself, or if that doesn't work, just copy them from my answer here.

Comment: I have tried that and are using the text editor. I have also been to the DB and it is standard quotes everywhere. I have also copied from the site that works. It makes no difference and it looks like WP outputs fancy quotes anyway. i would think it could relate to the theme, but even changing to the theme that works on site A it still don't work